# How to merge multiple columns using JSON in SQLite?

Tags: sql, json, sqlite

I have an SQLite database and there are multiple columns with the names like *"column1"*, *"column2"*, *"column3"* and so on, and I want to merge them into a single column named *"column"*, with its contents being the other columns' data in JSON format.

The resulting "column" would have a cell like this:

```
{
    "column1": 1234,
    "column2": 4567,
    ...
}
```

In order to achieve this, I think I should use a JSON extension for SQLite, but I couldn't figure out how to load it in *DataGrip IDE* or *SQLiteDatabaseBrowser*, and use it in SQL console.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html#build) describes how to load an extension, which you should do for the `json1` module.

Once the extension is loaded, you can use [scalar function `json_object()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jobj) to generate a valid json object, like so:

```
select
    t.*,
    json_object('column1', column1, 'column2', column2, 'column3', column3) as new_column
from mytable t
```

If you want to actually create a new column in the table:

```
alter table mytable add new_column text;    -- json objects are stored as TEXT
update mytable set new_column = json_object(
    'column1', column1, 'column2', column2, 'column3', column3
);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get all columns from a table without having to specify them?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, there are no SQLite extensions so json_object will not be available. In that case, use the contact operator instead.

instead of

```
SELECT json_object('column1', column1, 'column2', column2) AS merged FROM table
```

use

```
SELECT "{" || "column1"  || ":" || column1 || || "," || "column2"  || ":" || column2 ||  "}" AS merged FROM table
```

Comment: This kind of depends on which SQLite you will be using. E.g. with SQLCipher that is available.